# Difference between Scheme shell and Bash shell

Tags: bash, scripting, scheme, sh

Can anyone one please answer this question. I got some hints, but not clear-cut answer to the following question.

```
Compare Scheme shell, scsh to sh/bash. Which would you rather use from the 
keyboard? Which would you rather use for scripting?
```

Answer would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: scsh is not really intended for interactive use, but for lightweight system programming tasks where traditional shell scripting tends to fall short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) is a command processor, typically run in a text window, allowing the user to type commands which cause actions. Bash can also read commands from a file, called a script.

From [here](http://www.scsh.net/):-

> Scsh is an open-source Unix shell embedded within Scheme, running on
>   all major Unix platforms including AIX, Cygwin, Linux, FreeBSD, GNU
>   Hurd, HP-UX, Irix, Mac OS X, Solaris, and some others.
>
> Scsh is a variant of Scheme 48 (an R5RS compliant new-tech Scheme
>   system) Scsh is designed for writing real-life standalone Unix
>   programs and shell scripts. Scsh spans a wide range of application,
>   from “script” applications usually handled with perl or sh, to more
>   standard systems applications usually written in C.
>
> Scsh has two main components: a process notation for running programs
>   and setting up pipelines and redirections, and a complete syscall
>   library for low-level access to the operating system, i.e. to POSIX,
>   the least common denominator of more or less all Unices, plus widely
>   supported extensions such as symbolic links and BSD sockets. Moreover,
>   scsh provides an awk facility for pattern-directed computation over
>   streams of records, a rich facility for matching regular-expression
>   patterns in strings, event-based interrupt handling, user-level
>   threads, a futuristic module system, and an interactive environment.
>   Scsh comes with extensive documentation describing these and other
>   features.